# Default Username and password for motorola rfs6000 after factory reset

Tags: ieee-802.11

I have factory reset my Motorola rfs6000 by using

```
>cli
Username: restore
Password: restoreDefaultPassword
```

Which then asked me if i wanted to wipe the device etc etc.
But then after doing this, it comes up with the following;

```
ABS01-DEPOT-111412 Logon:
Password:
```

After looking around online, I was told to use the following

```
Username:admin
Password:Symbol
```

But I have tried this to no joy, as every time it tells me I have got an incorrect logon.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try "superuser" or lower case "s" on the symbol those are the ones I'm aware of

Comment: Try lower-case symbol instead of upper-case.

Comment: admin/motorola maybe. Is that device branded as Symbol?